# Capturar os valores do JSON que está Online

Tags: java, json

**Meu problema:**

Preciso ler um JSON que está em uma determinada URL. Tentei o seguinte código, porém não funciona:

```
JSONObject jsonObjeto;
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

URL url = new URL("http://www.exemplo.br/teste.json");

String x = url.openStream().toString();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(x));

jsonObjeto = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
```

**Recebo o seguinte erro:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
```

**Observações:**

- Esse código é um exemplo e não inclui o `try{}catch(...){}` no exemplo, alguém tem alguma noção de como resolver esse problema ou por que ele está ocorrendo?
- Tentei usar `String x = url.toString()` porém também obtive o mesmo erro.

Comment: Boa formatação de pergunta, tudo bem organizado :)

Comment: Olha, sei muito pouco de Java, mas você não deveria passar uma string para o parser, em vez de um StreamReader?

Comment: Bom a classe JSONparser possui dois método parse(String s) e parse(Reader in). Como estava lendo um JSON local usei o Reader, porém agora a necessidade é outra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você já tem o stream que é retornado pelo `openStream()`. É só passar como argumento do `InputStreamReader`:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() );
```

Comment: Obrigado, problema resolvido.Meu erro foi tentar usar o "getClass().getResourceAsStream(x)" e não deveria já que é um arquivo remoto. Obrigado @helderdarocha.

Answer (score 11):

Quando você chama o método `toString()` em um `InputStream`, ele não vai retornar o conteúdo do stream, e sim o endereço dele de memória. Leia um pouco mais sobre o método `toString()` [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Você deve pegar o stream da conexão http e utilizá-lo para construir um `Reader` e então usar o `JSONParser` para fazer o parse do JSON.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.exemplo.br/teste.json");
Reader br = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObjeto = (JSONObject) parser.parse(br);

System.out.println(jsonObjeto);
```

Answer (score 6):

O que você pode utilizar para não ter que fazer tudo na mão é o:

**com.google.common.io.Resources.**

Assim, para recuperar os dados da URL, é só fazer:

```
URL url = new URL( urlString );
return Resources.toString( url, Charsets.UTF_8 );
```

Outra dica é utilizar:

**com.google.gson.Gson.Gson()**

Para recuperar o objeto diretamente do JSON, assim:

```
new Gson().fromJson( objetoEmString, ClasseDestinoDaConversao.class );
```

Assim, com pouco código, está tudo pronto.

Documentações (em inglês):

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia.

Apenas tentando complementar as respostas anteriores, na hora de fazer o parse Objeto -> JSON/JSON -> Objeto, eu prefiro utilizar o [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Ele tem suporte a especificação JAXB. O que é bom pra você escrever um código menos acoplado ao framework.

Enfim. Tem um exemplo do site do [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) (que por sinal é um site que eu gosto muito de pegar exemplos) que acho que pode te ajudar. A única diferença é que ele lê o JSON de um arquivo, mas o princípio é o mesmo.

Você alterando a linha que lê o arquivo por `readTree(json)` (onde json é a String do JSON propriamente dita) já substitui.

O código é o seguinte.

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

        // read from file, convert it to user class
        User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);

        // display to console
        System.out.println(user);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado um pouco.