# Transformar Byte em String

Tags: java, criptografia

**Problema:**

---

Estou recebendo `byte` e quando tento transformar em `String` está dando erro.

```
...
byte[] msgBytes = ch.decode(hex, ch.key()); // retorna byte
String msgDecode = msgBytes.toString(); // tentando converter byte em String
System.out.println("Mensagem descriptografada [" + msgDecode + "]"); // Exibir
...
```

Já que `decode` me retorna alguns bytes, usei o `msgBytes.toString()`, acredito que não se faz a conversão deste modo. Alguém saber por que me retorna `[@549498794`.

Comment: O que tem em `ch`?

Comment: `ch` é meu objeto, `ChaveAES ch = new ChaveAES()`, `ChaveAES` é minha classe que faz `Encode` e `Decode` e outras tarefas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Retornou `[@549498794` porque o método `toString` de um `array` apenas usa o `toString` padrão da classe `Object`.

Para converter um array de bytes em String é possível usar o construtor da classe [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) que recebe, além do array de bytes o *encoding* a ser utilizado.

Exemplo:

```java
String msgDecode  = new String(msgBytes, "UTF-8");
```

É possível também usar o construtor sem o segundo parâmetro, mas nesse caso o Java irá usar o *encoding* padrão do sistema operacional, o que pode diminuir a interoperabilidade do seu código com outras plataformas.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou. Acabei fazendo essa confusão por que usei o `String x = "teste"; x.getBytes()` ai pensei que o `toString()` iria retornar um `String`.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é usar o método `toString()` a partir do array de bytes, como eu já aqui comentado [antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6351/1117). Dá uma lida na documentação e você vai entender como funciona o `toString`.

A solução é construir uma nova `String` a partir do array de bytes, assim:

```
...
byte[] msgBytes = ch.decode(hex, ch.key()); // retorna byte
String msgDecode = new String(msgBytes); // tentando converter byte em String
System.out.println("Mensagem descriptografada [" + msgDecode + "]"); // Exibir
...
```

Mais um vez, tente consultar o javadoc das classes que você está utilizando, há muita informação útil lá.